# What is the least position a club in EPL can finish with 30 wins?

Tags: logic, optimization, combinatorial-proofs

In EPL, 20 teams compete with one another. So any team has to play 38 matches (2 x 19). If a team were to end the season with 30 wins, what could be the least position they can finish? The least I could place them was at 5th. Is there any better answer?

EDIT: Ties are possible too.

In EPL, every win fetches you 3 points and a draw 1 point. If, at the end, two teams finish with the same points, then the team with the better GD (Goal Difference = Goals scored  - Goals conceded) is placed above.

Comment: Are ties possible?  If so, how do they affect the standings?  If one team has 25 wins and no ties, and another has 24 wins and 2 ties, which comes ahead of the other?

Comment: Ties are possible in this league. The rest, I've included in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Take $9$ teams including the one of interest and have them win at home and lose away against all the others in the group.  Then have them all beat the remaining $11$ teams both times because they scored $30$ wins each.  You now have $9$ teams tied with $30$ points.  If the team of interest gets beaten badly all the time and wins close games all the time, it will lose the tiebreaker to the other $8$, so it will come in $9$th.  You don't want ties because they decrease the total number of points.  We need lots of points to make lots of teams tie our heroes.

Answer (score 0):

The chart below shows that a team in the first round (games 1-19) could be tied with 8 other teams. The second round (games 20-38) could be identical and the same teams could be tied with 30 points. The loser of the run off would be in 9th place and have 30 points. This is the worst a team with 30 points could do.

[image]